# regex : all strings containing "tomcat/logs"

Tags: regex

I want to know how to match all strings containing `tomcat/logs` ?

For example : `/home/tomcat/logs`, `/etc/tomcat/logs`, `/home/folder/tomcat/logs`

Thanks.

Edited :

I'm using this for excluding backup directories, I need just regular expression independent of any specific language.

Comment: Please post what you have tried.

Comment: In what language do you need it?

Comment: What are you planning to DO with this match?  Let's avoid [XY Problem](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem)s.

Comment: @ghoti ok I edited the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this: (This is in `Python`)

```
>>> import re
>>> string_to_find_in = '/home/tomcat/logs'
>>> m = re.search('(.*tomcat\/logs)', string_to_find_in)
>>> m.group(0)
'/home/tomcat/logs'
```